# HTML Cache manifest URL relative to <base>

Tags: html, cache-manifest

We have a single-page app that uses `pushState` to change the URL in the browser. The app entry point - index.html downloaded each time no matter what the actual URL is - has it's `<base>` tag with `href` attribute set to some fixed URL (e.g. /myapp) as a context for a Tomcat server.

The problem is that we want to use HTML5's Cache Manifest that seems not to use the `<base>` href attribute when looking for the manifest file. For example:

When accessing the app through the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/view/detail
```

with index.html having:

```
<html manifest="app.manifest">
    ...
    <base href="/myapp">
```

then browser looks relatively to the current browser URL (myapp/view/detail) and not the base href path.

When manifest is specified as an absolute path:

```
<html manifest="/app.manifest">
```

then it looks for the file in the root (localhost:8080/).

But we need it to be resolved to `/myapp/app.manifest` (for portability reasons, we don't want to specify the server host/port in any of the URLs)

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm long gone from the company, and I have no memory of the solution :(